# Way to toggle x-axis label-grouping in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to make a vertical bar chart (aka "column graph") using Chart.js with multiple datasets that *does not* group by the x-axis labels. I would like each column to have its own label and I would like datasets to be grouped only by color. Chart.js automatically takes the first data entry of each dataset and plots it on the first x-axis label, and so on. Rather than that, I want my chart to look like this:

[image]

If this is simply a terrible way of presenting data, I'm open to other suggestions... But I like the alphabetical sorting of the show titles and the color-coded grouping of networks.